# Calculate time using formula speed=distance/time

Tags: c

Calculate time using formula speed=distance/time

but time always is 0 
my input is distance=10 and speed=5 and my output must = 2

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a, b, c, d;
    char time, distance, speed;

    printf("Enter Your distance ",a);
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("Enter Your speed ",b);
    scanf("%d", &b);

    time=distance/speed;
    printf("time is %d ",time);
}
```

Comment: without *units* the whole thing is meaningless. what is the distance? m? cm? km? miles?

Comment: Where did you assign to `distance` and `speed`?

Comment: Please read the manual page for scanf - it does return a value!

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, are you a teacher? How did you know that units are not implied? Why do you think that this is the average speed rather than the end speed (after acceleration)?

Answer (score 4):

You're using integers (integer arithmetic) instead of floats.

An integer can be four bytes, but does not contain any decimals (`0`, `150035`, but it can't be `3.1251`). Floats are four bytes as well (most of the time), and do contain decimals (`3.14`), however, the overall range of floats is lower and harder to predict.

You're also using `char`s (1 byte). 1 byte = 8 bits so their minimum is -128 and there maximum is 127.

Try this:

```
float time, distance, speed;
time = distance / speed;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are having speed and distance as `int` so the time you get is `int`.
e.g.

`distance=5`
 `speed=2`
 `time=5/2` which is 2.5 but in order to make it `int` it is truncated and becomes 2.

Plus I coudn't make out where you assign values to `time` , `speed` and `distance` from `a`,`b` that you read. Also making `time`,`distance`, `speed` as `char` doesn't seem a good idea.

```
float time, distance, speed;

printf("Enter Your distance ");
scanf("%f", &distance);
printf("Enter Your speed ");
scanf("%f", &speed);
time=distance/speed;
printf("time is %f",time);
```

This should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Typos:
1. You declared `time`, `distance` & `speed` as `char`.
2. You are storing the input for distance and speed in `a` and `b`.
3. `printf("Enter Your distance ",a);` is not a valid syntax for input.

Try this

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    double time, distance, speed;

    printf("Enter Your distance: ");
    scanf("%f", &distance);
    printf("Enter Your speed: ");
    scanf("%f", &speed);

    time=distance/speed;
    printf("time is %f ",time);

}
```

Comment: double time, distance, speed; is wrong the correct one is int time, distance, speed;

Comment: @AhsanKhan; What happens if user input 100.7 for `distance` and `50.9` for `speed`?

Comment: @hacks I forgot to mention that my input is distance=10 and speed=5 and my output must = 2 

sorry for that..

Answer (score 0):

You should declare time,distance and speed in float if you are going to use decimal inputs and if you want to get a decimal output.

```
`#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float time, distance, speed;
    printf("Enter Your distance: \n");
    scanf("%.2f\n", &distance);
    printf("Enter Your speed: \n");
    scanf("%.2f\n", &speed);
    time=distance/speed;
    printf("time is %.2f ",time);
}`
```